# how can I get all the photos of the device?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic. I want to print all the photo from the gallery in my app.

I know that I can use camera plugin to let the user to select an image.

But I don't want the user select an image, I will have all the images from the gallery and have the path to print them.

Anybody know how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker, i think this is a popular question

Comment: This plugin don't ask the question, the user has to choose the images. I don't want that the user has to choose images, but show all the photos in my app

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to use [cordova-gallery-api](https://github.com/subitolabs/cordova-gallery-api) which offer methods to query gallery albums and media.

**To install the plugin:**

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/subitolabs/cordova-gallery-api.git
```

**Sample Code:**

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function()
{
    var $content = document.getElementById("content");

    $content.innerHTML = "Loading albums ...";

    galleryAPI.getAlbums(function(items)
    {
        var html = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {
            var album = items[i];

            html += '<a href="javascript:loadAlbum(\'' + album.title + '\')" class="album"><span>' + escape(album.title) + '</span></a>';
        }

        $content.innerHTML = html;

    }, function(error){alert(error);});

    window.loadAlbum = function(albumName)
    {
        galleryAPI.getMedia(albumName, function(items)
        {
            var html = "";

            for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            {
                var media = items[i];

                html += '<a href="javascript:void()" class="media"><img src="file://' + media.thumbnail + '" /></a>';
            }

            $content.innerHTML = html;

        }, function(error){alert(error);});
    };

}, false);
```